# javaserverfaces property access problem

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have index.html page with

```
<h:dataTable id="usersTable" value="#{mainViewController.users}" var="user" border="1">
 ....
```

and request scoped mainViewController bean

```
@Component("mainViewController")
@Scope("request")
public class MainViewController {
@Inject
private UserDao userDao;
private Collection<User> users;

public Collection<User> getUsers() {
    if (users == null) {
        users = userDao.findAll();
    }
    return users;
}
```

when I access index.html getUsers is called, that is absolutely normal, but when I leave index.html to some other page getUsers is also called, how avoid secondary call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use POST for page-to-page navigation. So don't use a `<h:commandLink>` or `<h:commandButton>` to navigate to another page. It will unnecessarily submit the form to the server and recreate the same bean. Just use `<a>`, `<h:outputLink>`, `<h:link>` or `<h:button>` for page-to-page navigation. They fire a GET request straight on the target URL.

Another advantage of using GET for page-to-page navigation is that Searchbots will index the pages. Thus, better for SEO.